# Is it less than $100 or under $100? Is it more than $100 or is it over $100?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, american-english

I am building a web site and need to clarify something for a non-U.S. customer.  It's whether to use "less than/more than" or "under/over".

- items less than $100.00
- items from $100.00 to $500.00
- items more than $500.00

Or should it be

- items under $100.00
- items from $100.00 to $500.00
- items over $500.00

Is there one that is blatantly wrong?

Comment: Just as a personal preference, I think the second one is more suitable (by being more concise and keeping the numbers in line better). As JSBᾶngs wrote, both are fine.

Comment: If clarity is vital but vocabulary is not limited, the words 'cheaper' and 'more expensive' might be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of your variants are grammatically correct, and will be easily understood by native English speakers. The *less than X* is idiomatically identical to *under X* when referring to monetary amounts, as is *more than X* with *over X*.

However, if your audience is international, you might prefer to say *items costing less than X* or *items costing more than X* simply to avoid any possibility of confusion or ambiguity.

Comment: It's definitely a U.S. audience.